# Optimal path between source and destination - android

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, dijkstra

I'm new to android development and I've done some applications involving Google maps. What I'm trying to develop now is an Optimal Path Finder App. I know that there are many application already available for this purpose, but I plan to do this on my own. I'm planning to use Dijkstra's algorithm for this purpose. The initial input is the source and destination, and the output must be the optimal path drawn on a Google map between the source and destination. I've an idea about the steps needed to do this application.

Step 1 : Extract the intermediate places between the source and destination.
Step 2 : Add these nodes to a graph data structure.
Step 3 : Apply Dijkstra's Algorithm and find the path.
Step 4 : Draw the path on a Google map.

Am I thinking in the right way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you're thinking in the right way :) ! Also consider openstreetmaps for the data source and mapsforge as an offline map tile provider.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1.put `ruledijkstra.html` onto folder asset

2.load using this code:

```
private void getLocation(){
    WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();

    mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/maps.html");
    String path="javascript:loadAtStart(-6.184505,106.797685,11)";
    mWebView.loadUrl(path);
}
```

3.code for asset: 
`ruledijkstra.html` or you can google:etc
http://www.zlink.com.br/optimap/index.php?&loc0=-7.1209077392192785,-34.9075984954834&loc1=-7.121418750873643,-34.903221130371094&loc2=-7.128828355854018,-34.93025779724121